# Get the first and last matching alphanumeric pattern using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am working on parsing some data. For that I want to find the first matching pattern and last matching pattern in a line having many such similar patterns.

I have many lines like this:

```
my $str = 'line1:(sat.....mat,bull...horse,gre....toefl,usa..canada)'
```

and I want results to be:

```
sat    canada
```

There could be more or less number of 'pairs' in other lines.

This is the code that I have:

```
if ($str =~ /[a-z]:\(([a-z]+).*?([a-z]+)\S*/){
    my $first = $1;
    my $second = $2;
    print $first."\t".$second."\n";
}
```

but this ends up returning:

```
sat    mat
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/:\(([a-z]+).*?([a-z]+)\)/
```

If the last word should be just before a closing round bracket then it would be above.

Comment: this seems the most accurate answer ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = 'line1:(sat.....mat,bull...horse,gre....toefl,usa..canada)';

if ($str =~ /[a-z0-9]+:\((\w+).*\.+(\w+)/)
{
    print $1."\t".$2."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
sat canada
```

Answer (score 1):

You catch the first and second match of your expression. If you add the closing bracket behind your second matching, the match just before that bracket will be catched.

Also edit the match before the opening bracket. 
So it would be just:

```
[a-z0-9]+:\(([a-z]+).*?([a-z]+)\)\S*
```